# Paired ToggleButtons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, button

I'm pretty sure someone will have done something like this before but have been hitting my head on this for a few days now, with little headway.

I have a WPF form which is being used to compare trades. The trades differ on certain "break" fields. The form is to be used to select one "lead" trade and one of the remaining trades is selected as the active break trade. On those fields that differ between the two, the form displays toggle buttons in place of the value, allowing the user to select which field on which trade to use as the valid value.

Any ideas how best to implement this? I've tried pairing the lead and active trades in my ViewModel and hooking into the PropertyChanged event but have to kludge each and every property to avoid stack overflows. Any help appreciated, preferably in MVVM style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding completely, but isn't what you're looking for a RadioButton? You can style it to look like a normal button if you want to.